# Securely sharing a folder on a wifi network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, security

I was successfully able to share an external hard drive between my mac and Windows machine over wifi by enabling file sharing in the Windows properties of the selected drive (see method [HERE](https://superuser.com/a/1285293/598567)). What I have discovered is that by doing this I have created a security risk by opening the following ports:
 **TCP 139, 445
 UDP 137, 138**
(see description of security issue [HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402(v=ws.11).aspx))

What I need to know now is this: How do I enable this file sharing securely so that there are not constant brute force attacks on this port?

Running Windows7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your home network and you have the typical router/firewall combo that comes with the service, then you are safe.  Those ports are open on the *internal* LAN, but not accessible through the internet.  Those ports are blocked by default.

Comment: i am on a home network that is password protected,but was concerned because of that article I posted in my 2nd link. I had problems last year when trying to share my screen over my home network. Thousands of brute force attacks everyday trying to get in.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid *Everyone* gets brute force attacks.  Thats the norm in todays world.  Hacker bots scan IPs and see open ports and try to get in.  Thats the way it goes.

Comment: that's what I thought. So its not secure then. I am still looking for a secure way to share a drive on my home network between 2 computers. ALso your last statement contradicts your answer.

Comment: You don't mention how you were sharing your screen but enabling file sharing, only allows devices within your own network, access your files.

Comment: @Ramhound i used the past tense, as in I HAD BEEN (past tense) using screen sharing but disabled it after seeing the amount of brute force attempts daily. Cheers

Comment: @Ramhound please see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402(v=ws.11).aspx