# Boot Micro PC remotely via WiFi

Tags: boot, remote-access, remote, pxe

I have a Micro PC (Intel Atom Bay Trail T-CR Z3735F) and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to wake it up remotely, whether through network (WoWLAN, PXE or so) or through some AC Power Failure features. I've already enabled PXE Boot capability in BIOS. Moreover, I suspect that this WiFi card supports WoWLAN but I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is possible to boot on PXE over a WiFi device?](http://superuser.com/questions/310915/is-possible-to-boot-on-pxe-over-a-wifi-device)

Comment: PXE Booting is not mandatory, I'll accept all solutions. My goal is to wake up this PC from Hibernation/Shutdown but this has to be done through WiFi

Comment: You need to make sure the system supports that capability. It's not enough to have WoWLAN-compliant NIC. BIOS needs to allow that as well, and hardware, of course. I believe it's a question for the manufacturer.